# How to locate the node in JCR using uuid from query

Tags: sql, aem, jcr

This is the error I get.

> 16.03.2016 12:02:16.413 *WARN* [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [1458147736268] GET /en/employees-leaders/employee-s-toolkit2/epd-update/epd-update-archives/caterpillar-news/upcoming-brand-webinarfocusonmarketing.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.LanguageManagerImpl Error while
>   retrieving language property. javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: cannot
>   read item xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (alpha-numeric)

I am trying to locate the node in JCR using the xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, which I believe is uuid, using a query in AEM.

- Is the xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx actually a uuid?
- How do I locate the source i.e node, causing the issue?

I tried running a sql with the above id in the jcr, but it returned no result.

```
//*[jcr:contains(., '91186155-45ad-474-9ad9-d5156a398629')] order by @jcr:score descending
```

Any other insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a query if you know the Node's UUID, just use the [Session.getNodeByIdentifier(String id)](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html#getNodeByIdentifier%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: This looks promising. Since I am trying to troubleshoot, is there a way to run the method in some sort of a console in JCR (similar to dev tools)? or does it have to be coded and compiled? Thanks.

Comment: You can run code directly on the server by using AEM Fiddle from the ACS tools library: http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/aem-fiddle.html

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not SQL as you stated, it's XPATH. Is that a typo or did you run the query incorrectly?

It certainly looks like a UUID. You can query for the `jcr:uuid` property or you can continue doing a full text search.

XPATH:

`/jcr:root//*[jcr:contains(., '91186155-45ad-474-9ad9-d5156a398629')]`

`/jcr:root//*[@jcr:uuid='91186155-45ad-474-9ad9-d5156a398629']`

JCR-SQL2:

`SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE contains(s.*, '91186155-45ad-474-9ad9-d5156a398629')`

`SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE [jcr:uuid] = '91186155-45ad-474-9ad9-d5156a398629'`

What read permissions does your account have? You're going to find a lot of results for a `jcr:uuid` query will be under `/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage`.

Comment: I ran both. But the results are empty, making me think it is not a uuid. I have admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Use QueryBuilderDebugger, (localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html) and run similar query as below to get the node for a given uuid:

```
property=jcr:uuid
property.value=e69b256e-a466-3730-866b-de22c82ab8ck
path=/home
type=rep:Group
p.limit=10
```